# Use Not Exist Instead of Not IN -

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to use NOT EXIST with below query instead of NOT IN.

`Select * From Currencymaster Where Currencycode Not In ('USD');`

I tried to write it like this:

`Select currencycode from currencymaster where not exists (select currencycode from currencymaster where currencycode='USD');`

I am not sure whether this is correct. Because its not giving me any result.

Please verify or guide me to rewrite it.
Thanks

Comment: Please show some sample data and the desired result. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your NOT IN() query selects all rows that do not have a currencycode on USD -- your NOT EXISTS()  query selects all rows from currencymaster as long as there is not a single row with currencycode of USD.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select currencycode  
  from currencymaster a
 where not exists (select currencycode 
                     from currencymaster b 
                    where b.currencycode='USD' 
                      and a.currencycode=b.currencycode);
```

`select currencycode from currencymaster where currencycode='USD'` will always return row in your condtion bcause it always found a row where `currencycode='USD`.To Make it work you have to add another and condition the check whaeater the main table ROW i.e A have Currency='USD'.

If you only on curency to check than you can try like this..

```
 Select currencycode  
      from currencymaster WHERE currencycode!='USD'
```

Comment: Your answer is Towards the Question is Correct. But I seem, it is not feasible to use same table twice just for using `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @RJ1990 the answer here is depend how OP want...however you can suggest him/her about better things...

Comment: The better thing is to use the original NOT IN (). This approach has no advantages, and is more wordy and complex and would run slower.

Comment: @AmitSingh- You have given the answer I asked, the entire idea was to use NOT EXIST instead of NOT IN. I did not post the entire query here. But still you answered. It meets the requirement.